# myslqi query keeps returning Boolean after prepared statment

Tags: php, mysqli

The first half of this works correctly. `$selectedVerb` and `$verbNum` both come back fine and are displayed. When I try to use `$verbNum` in the next query, it keeps resulting in error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array()
>   on boolean; Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown.

Code:

```
if ($stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT verbNum FROM verblist WHERE mainVerb = ? ")){

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $selectedVerb);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($verbNum);

    $stmt->fetch();

    echo '<span>'.$selectedVerb.' is part of verb number: '.$verbNum. '</span>';

    settype($verbNum, "integer");

    $verbListarray = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT mainVerb FROM verblist WHERE verbNum = $verbNum");

    while($row = $verbListarray->fetch_array())
    {
        echo $row['mainVerb'];
        echo "<br />";
    }    

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should [find out why](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: first you're using a string but then trying to pass it off as an integer, *huh??* That won't work.

Comment: Check is ```$verbListarray``` true or false. If it is false, it may be caused by query failure.

Comment: I was under the assumption that $verbNum is an int in all it's references.

Comment: ........... it isn't.

Comment: also why you OOP way with procedural way

Comment: Integers and strings are two different animals.

Comment: given the comment *"Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll() "* - well we know what that's about, least "I" do.

Comment: @scott.schaffer What is the error message you get from [`mysqli_error()`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_error)?

Comment: I see references to `fetchAll` - where is that being called and isn't that the PDO syntax?

Comment: @RamRaider that was in the answer provided below, and was subsequently edited out.

Comment: oic - late to the party again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing OOP way with procedural way is not a good way to go, so do like below:-

```
if ($stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT verbNum FROM verblist WHERE mainVerb = ? ")){

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $selectedVerb);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($verbNum);

    $stmt->fetch();

    echo '<span>'.$selectedVerb.' is part of verb number: '.$verbNum. '</span>';

    //settype($verbNum, "integer");

    $stmt->close();

    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT mainVerb FROM verblist WHERE verbNum = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $verbNum);

    $stmt->execute();

     while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo $row['mainVerb'];
        echo "<br />";
      }    

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: thanks for actually giving me some direction instead of answering with snark. What you posted is still giving me an error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll()

Comment: @scott.schaffer  use `fetch()` then. check my edited solution

Comment: *"Don't mix OOP way with procedural way"* - what's wrong about that? it's allowed. And your method here's wrong. The solution simpler than this really.

Comment: `fetchAll()` is PDO here, yet another different animal that's been said to go around.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner how would you go about fixing my original code?

Comment: @AlivetoDie is the bind_result(verbListarray) actually storing the whole array or just one entry of the DB?

Comment: @scott.schaffer  you have to tell me. that's wy i used print_r() there. check how many records coming

Comment: @scott.schaffer Each call to `fetch()` fetches one row, and sets `$verbListArray` to the column from that row.

Comment: So the "array" in the variable name is misleading, it will just be a string.

Answer (score 1):

There's no good reason to do multiple queries in a loop, just join the two queries.

```
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("
    SELECT t1.verbNum, t2.mainVerb
    FROM verblist AS t1
    JOIN verblist AS t2 ON t1.verbNum = t2.verbNum
    WHERE t1.mainVerb = ?
    ORDER BY t1.verbNum")
$stmt->bind_param("s", $selectedVerb);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($verbNum, $mainVerb);
$firstRow = true;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($firstRow) {
        echo '<span>'.$selectedVerb.' is part of verb number: '.$verbNum. '</span>';
        $firstRow = false;
    }
    echo $mainVerb . "<br>";
}
```